# Angular 2 incremental counter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

i'm strugling with counting and incrementing a number in a for. I'm using Angular 2, typescript, Ionic 2 and Firebase.

Here's the deal, i'm queryng something from firebase, since it's a object i can't use **.length** on it so i declared a **counter: number = 0;** in the top of my code and inside my **snapshot.val()** i'm incrementing it, but in the end when i do a **console.log** it's **0**.

Here is my code (i've took away useless code to post here):

```
firebase.database().ref('MedicoPacientes/' + id).once('value', snapshot => {
   for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
                    //PEGA TUDO DENTRO DO HISTORICO DE UM USUARIO QUE SEJA TRUE
                    historico.child(key).orderByChild('permissoes').equalTo(true).once('value', snap => {
      for (var key in snap.val()) {
                            this.counter++;
                            //also tryed this.counter += 1 and this.counter = this.counter +1;
                        }
                    });

                    historico.child(key).orderByChild('permissoes/' + cpf).equalTo(id).once('value', snap => {
                        for (var key in snap.val()) {
                            this.counter++;
                            //also tryed this.counter += 1 and this.counter = this.counter +1;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
```

So it's a for inside a for because i need to get a key before getting the registers i need to count.
Algo i'm saving this registers in a variable that is the object (it's the part i've took from the code to post here) and i also tryed iterating this object and incrementing it

in the start of my code i have:

```
export class MedicoAlertasPage {
  counter: number = 0;
```

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?

### EDIT 1

Here is the complete page code:

```
export class MedicoAlertasPage {

paciente: any;
semHistorico: boolean;
limit: any;
counter: number = 0;
meuId: any;
contador: number = 15;

alertas: any[] = [];
alertasFiltrado: any[];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage, public loading: LoadingController) {
}

//COPY THE VALUES TO USE IN THE FILTER
inicializaAlertas() {
    this.alertasFiltrado = this.alertas;
}

//FILTER ON TYPING
filtraAcompanhamentos(ev: any) {
    this.inicializaAlertas();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
        this.alertasFiltrado = this.alertasFiltrado.filter((item) => {
            return (item.nome.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
        })
    }
}

//LOAD USER HISTORY
ionViewWillEnter() {
    let l = this.loading.create({ content: "Aguarde..." });
    l.present();

    this.storage.get('id').then(id => {
        this.storage.get('cpf').then(cpf => {
            let historico = firebase.database().ref('/Historico/');
            firebase.database().ref('MedicoPacientes/' + id).once('value', snapshot => {
                for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
                    //GET ALL THE DATA THAT IS TRUE
                    historico.child(key).orderByChild('permissoes').equalTo(true).once('value', snap => {
                        for (var key in snap.val()) {
                            this.counter++;
                            this.alertas.unshift({
                                chave: key,
                                data: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
                                hora: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('HH:mm'),
                                descricao: snap.val()[key].descricao,
                                paciente: snap.val()[key].nome
                            });
                        }
                    });

                    //GET ALL DATA OF A SELECTED USER
                    historico.child(key).orderByChild('permissoes/' + cpf).equalTo(id).once('value', snap => {
                        for (var key in snap.val()) {
                            this.counter++;
                            this.alertas.unshift({
                                chave: key,
                                data: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
                                hora: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('HH:mm'),
                                descricao: snap.val()[key].descricao,
                                paciente: snap.val()[key].nome
                            });
                        }
                    })
                }
                this.inicializaAlertas();
                l.dismiss();
            })
        });
    })

}

}
```

Comment: the this is the same object that contain counter? ..can you debug and check on what this is referred?

Comment: Can you put the complete code of MedicoAlertasPage?

Comment: @aminarghavani just edited and now it has the entire code

Comment: Where are you putting your `console.log();`?

Comment: @aminarghavani inside inicializaAlertas() method

Comment: `this.inicializaAlertas();` runs before other codes. try to call it with an action button from inside you page. i mean after `ionViewWillEnter()` finished.

Comment: @aminarghavani but i'm calling it in the end of my IonViewWillEnter and it's loading the content as expected, i could try calling it in a IonViewDidEnter, but i think the results will be the same

Comment: Is this really the minimal code required to reproduce the problem? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    let l = this.loading.create({ content: "Aguarde..." });
    l.present();

    this.storage.get('id').then(id => {
        this.storage.get('cpf').then(cpf => {
            let historico = firebase.database().ref('/Historico/');
            firebase.database().ref('MedicoPacientes/' + id).once('value', snapshot => {
                for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
                    //GET ALL THE DATA THAT IS TRUE
                    historico.child(key).orderByChild('permissoes').equalTo(true).once('value', snap => {
                        for (var key in snap.val()) {
                            this.counter++;
                            this.alertas.unshift({
                                chave: key,
                                data: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
                                hora: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('HH:mm'),
                                descricao: snap.val()[key].descricao,
                                paciente: snap.val()[key].nome
                            });
                        }
                        //GET ALL DATA OF A SELECTED USER
                        historico.child(key).orderByChild('permissoes/' + cpf).equalTo(id).once('value', snap => {
                            for (var key in snap.val()) {
                                this.counter++;
                                this.alertas.unshift({
                                    chave: key,
                                    data: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('DD/MM/YYYY'),
                                    hora: Moment.unix(Number(key)).format('HH:mm'),
                                    descricao: snap.val()[key].descricao,
                                    paciente: snap.val()[key].nome
                                });
                            }
                            this.inicializaAlertas();
                            l.dismiss();
                        })

                    });


                }

            })
        });
    })

}
```